# Error message (Incorrect number of subscripts) when trying to use iNext()

Tags: r, inext

I'm having some issues running iNEXT with this new dataset

I'm trying to get species estimates as well as sample-coverage based accumulation curve from camera trapping efforts. But am having issues with loading the dataset into iNEXT.

I've followed the format of the incidence_raw data example given in the iNEXT manual (ciliates) but to no avail.

Here's the data and how I tried to convert the data into a species incidence matrix (row = species; every column = sampling unit):

```
#load packages

library(iNEXT)

#data here
ct <-structure(list(Station = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CT01", 
"CT02", "CT03"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(10L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 2L), .Label = c("1/11/19", "13/11/19", "14/11/19", 
"15/11/19", "17/11/19", "18/11/19", "22/11/19", "23/11/19", "25/10/19", 
"26/10/19", "27/10/10", "27/10/19", "28/10/19", "29/10/19", "3/11/19", 
"30/10/19", "31/10/19", "6/11/19", "7/11/19"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(23L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 24L, 15L, 31L, 20L, 
    18L, 19L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 9L, 14L), .Label = c("0:34:24", 
    "0:43:46", "13:07:10", "16:49:34", "17:26:28", "19:06:56", 
    "19:11:56", "19:13:28", "19:34:58", "19:53:00", "19:56:42", 
    "2:33:36", "2:34:40", "20:21:42", "20:27:00", "20:31:42", 
    "20:32:08", "22:25:22", "23:19:00", "23:50:24", "23:50:44", 
    "3:19:00", "4:26:00", "4:28:00", "4:46:00", "4:56:04", "5:13:32", 
    "5:18:00", "5:19:00", "5:56:00", "6:31:00"), class = "factor"), 
    DateTimeOriginal = structure(c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
    20L, 17L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 24L, 
    25L, 3L), .Label = c("1/11/19 0:43", "1/11/19 19:13", "13/11/19 20:21", 
    "14/11/19 17:26", "15/11/19 19:56", "17/11/19 0:34", "18/11/19 4:56", 
    "22/11/19 5:13", "23/11/19 2:33", "23/11/19 2:34", "3/11/19 13:07", 
    "3/11/19 19:06", "3/11/19 19:11", "3/11/19 20:31", "3/11/19 20:32", 
    "30/10/19 23:22", "30/10/19 23:50", "30/10/19 23:58", "30/10/19 23:59", 
    "31/10/19 0:00", "31/10/19 16:49", "31/10/19 22:25", "31/10/19 23:19", 
    "6/11/19 23:50", "7/11/19 19:34"), class = "factor"), Scientific_name_1 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Callosciurus_notatus", "Rattus_tiomanicus"
    ), class = "factor"), Abundance_1 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L
    )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")


ct$trapnights <- paste(ct$Station, ct$Date, sep="_") 

#create contingency table
ct.matrix <- xtabs(Abundance_1~Scientific_name_1+trapnights, data=ct)


#create species incidence matrix
ct.df1 <- ifelse(ct.matrix>0,1,0) 


#run iNEXT
ct.inext <- iNEXT(ct.df2, datatype="incidence_raw")
```

At this point, I'll run into this error:

```
Error in arr[1, , ] <- t(as.matrix(ChaoSpecies(x, datatype, conf))) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
```

I'm almost positive it's something wrong with my formatting but I'm just not sure where the problem lies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Please specify the packages used

Comment: JoanLee, providing data via links is often a bad idea on Stack sites: when the link goes stale (**this data link has already failed, btw**), the question becomes unreproducible. It is typically better to include *sample* data within the question itself via `dput(head(x,20))` or `data.frame(...)` (as many rows as necessary to adequately represent the data and still reproduce the question/problem). Thanks

Comment: I've updated to specify the package and the sample data. Thank you for the feedback and please let me know if I'd need to give more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with iNEXT. However, I could see that when datatype="incidence_raw", x should be a list. I converted the ct.df1 to list and tried. Here's the output.

```
> ct.df1 <- ifelse(ct.matrix>0,1,0) 
> ct.df2<- list(ct.df1)
> ct.inext <- iNEXT(ct.df2, datatype="incidence_raw")
> ct.inext
Compare 1 assemblages with Hill number order q = .
$class: iNEXT

$DataInfo: basic data information
    site  T  U S.obs SC Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10
1 site.1 14 15     2  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0

$iNextEst: diversity estimates with rarefied and extrapolated samples.
[[1]]
    t       method order    qD qD.LCL qD.UCL    SC SC.LCL SC.UCL
1   1 interpolated     0 1.071  0.922  1.221 0.933  0.828  1.000
2   1 interpolated     0 1.071  0.922  1.221 0.933  0.828  1.000
10  7 interpolated     0 1.500  0.839  2.161 0.933  0.878  0.989
11  7 interpolated     0 1.500  0.839  2.161 0.933  0.878  0.989
20 14     observed     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
30 21 extrapolated     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
31 21 extrapolated     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000
40 28 extrapolated     0 2.000  1.111  2.889 1.000  1.000  1.000


$AsyEst: asymptotic diversity estimates along with related statistics.
  Site         Diversity Observed Estimator  s.e.   LCL   UCL
1    A  Species richness    2.000     2.000 0.472 2.000 3.585
2    A Shannon diversity    1.278     1.324 0.218 1.278 1.751
3    A Simpson diversity    1.142     1.143 0.129 1.142 1.396

NOTE: Only show five estimates, call iNEXT.object$iNextEst. to show complete output.
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Can I ask how do you tell what x should be based on the datatype?

Comment: You are welcome! I have update the link in my edited answer.